# How to pass HashMap values as a queryParam to Gatling simulation

Tags: scala, performance-testing, scala-collections, gatling

I need help for passing HashMap to queryParam as shown below, as I have so many request with same queryParams and just last queryParam changes with each request.

```
val asset_sort_by_displays = exec(http("Sort by Displays")
 .get("/data/analytics/reports/")
 .queryParamMap(GatlingConfig.asset_query_string_map)
 .queryParam("""sort""", """displays""")
```

Where in my config file I have a object GatlingConfig{} where I've defined asset_query_string_map as.

```
val asset_query_string_map = Map("""report_type""" -> """performance""",
 """start_date""" -> "2014-07-07",
 """end_date""" -> "2014-07-10",
 """metrics""" ->  """plays""",
 """metrics""" -> """displays""",
 """metrics""" -> """video_starts""")
```

But, it throws `" value asset_query_string_map is not a member of io.gatling.http.request.builder.HttpRequestBuilder "` error.

Please guide me , how can I pass Map value to queryParams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where in my config file I have created

I don't get it. This is to be defined in some Scala code and imported/placed in scope.

Then, queryParam is for unique values. You'd have to use queryParamMap instead.

With current snapshot, you'd have:

```
val asset_query_string_map = Map("""report_type""" -> """performance""",
   """start_date""" -> "2014-07-07",
   """end_date""" -> "2014-07-10",
   """metrics""" ->  """plays""",
   """metrics""" -> """displays""",
   """metrics""" -> """video_starts""")

val asset_sort_by_displays = exec(http("Sort by Displays")
  .get("/data/analytics/reports/")
  .queryParamMap(asset_query_string_map)
  .queryParam("""sort""", """displays"""))
```

Comment: I have a config.scala file with object GatlingConfig{}  where I've defined asset_query_string_map. using queryParamMap it throws                                                                  gatling-charts-highcharts-2.0.0-SNAP
SHOT\user-files\simulations\delphi_ui\lib\Asset.scala:19: value queryParamMap is not a member of io.gat
ling.http.request.builder.HttpRequestBuilder
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value queryParamMap'?
16:15:15.867 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ -  .queryParamMap(GatlingConfig.asset_query_string_map)
16:15:15.868 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ -   ^

Comment: You're probably using an old snapshot. This method used to be named `queryParamsMap` (with an s).

Comment: Please update your answer for queryParamsMap (with an s), i can accept it and will be helpful to other world. thanks for help.

Comment: I'd better not: you're the one using an old snapshot, the current one doesn't have an s, and that's what the API will look like in upcoming Gatling 2.

Comment: Now param changed to :-  queryParam and queryParamsMap changed to :- queryParamMap. Is there any documentation where end user can find what are the changes in every build?

Comment: By definition, shapshots change. If you want to upgrade them, you'd better what the project on Github and check the commit log.

Comment: Plus, changes between stable versions are documented in the migration guide: http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/#migrating-from-a-previous-version-of-gatling

Comment: Thanks, it will be helpful